# React Native setState with sent variable

Tags: native, react-native, setstate

I want to know how to send a variable through when text in an input field is altered to alter a particular variable so I can reuse the same function.

```
var app = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
  gender: 'Male',
  name: '',
};
},
render: function() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.input}
      ref="gender"
      onChangeText={this.handleChange}
      placeholder={this.state.gender} />
    <TextInput style={styles.input}
      ref="name"
      onChangeText={this.handleChange}
      placeholder="name" />
  </View>
);
},
handleChange: function(text) {
  this.setState({gender: text});
}
```

As it is when changing the text it alters the state of 'gender' but I want it to change the 'name' state if I alter that one, all with the same function. Also I need to add other fields where if the text is altered it would alter the state of that variable with the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that takes two arguments, then check to set the state of the desired variable:

```
handleChange: function(text, arg2) {
  if(arg2 == 'gender') {
    this.setState({
      gender: text
    });
  } else if(arg2 == 'name') {
    this.setState({
      name: text
    });
  }
}
```

[Here](https://rnplay.org/apps/DX6Nrg) is a sample app with the functionality implemented:

https://rnplay.org/apps/DX6Nrg

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} = React;

var App = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
  gender: 'Gender is not yet set...',
  name: 'Name is not yet set...',
};
},
  handleChange: function(text, arg2) {
  if(arg2 == 'gender') {
    this.setState({
      gender: "gender is " + text
    });
  } else if(arg2 == 'name') {
    this.setState({
      name: "name is " + text
    });
  }
},
render: function() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height:50}}
      ref="gender"
      onChangeText={(text) => {this.handleChange(text, 'gender')}}
      placeholder="Gender" />
    <TextInput style={{marginTop:10, backgroundColor: 'blue', height:50}}
      ref="name"
      onChangeText={(text) => {this.handleChange(text, 'name')}}
      placeholder="name" />

        <Text style={{marginTop:10, fontSize:20}}>{this.state.gender}</Text>
            <Text style={{marginTop:10, fontSize:20}}>{this.state.name}</Text>
  </View>
);
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:50
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Comment: But that seems very long winded, I really want to keep the handleChange function to just one line. Isn't there any way to pass the 'ref' to the function so it knows its ref='gender' or ref='name'?

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be possible to get all of that functionality into one line, is there a reason that you need it to do so? You can definitely set the refs, but not sure if that would be any less verbose than the above function. You could also of course refactor my function to be less verbose, but in my eyes it is a fair example implementing the functionality I think you were aiming for.